# Twitter large Images using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I have created 2 blogposts in wordpress and shared them in twitter.

The twitter URLs are

https://twitter.com/Jagannathan6/status/1423662392534175744?s=20

and the other is

https://twitter.com/Jagannathan6/status/1423197036195717124?s=20

As you see the image appears as a thumbnail in one tweet and as a large image in another. How to make the thumbnail image appear as a large image? Has it got something with the size of the image?

I am looking for an answer where I need not get premium version of wordpress.

Comment: What’s the programming question here? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Its a programming question only. I am not sure whether it can be done via customisation of some meta tags

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use Yoast plugin. Taking a look at the two tweets I'm wondering:

1. Are you using media sizes to size the images (Wordpress takes the largest image it can and resizes and/or crops smaller images to fit the sizes in the Media options menu)?
2. Are you using Yoast or custom hooks to post the images to twitter?
3. Are you using the same size images for both posts?
4. Are you attaching the images as Featured Images in the editor in the same way?
5. Did you post them to twitter in the same way?
6. Do both posts have snippets / excerpts applied to them? If not, make sure your theme is calling the_excerpt, or else you've configured the excerpt to pull from the main body of the post, or else hand-craft the excerpt in the relevant meta box.
7. Do both images have meta tags / alt tags applied to them? Check in the Media Library or in the post > edit image and see that alt text, caption and description are all filled out.
8. Did you test the images first with https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator ?